# Authentication using ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, api, express, authentication, post

I want to integrate with an authentication server by providing the header request and request with user's password (base64 encrypted) and username. I have the following API that I need to implement using ExpressJS.

**Request Header**

```
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Basic aW50.......
Basic Authentication
Username: xyz
Password: ********
```

**Request**

```
{
  "userName": "abc",
  "password: "*****"
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have tried and tell what is the problem with it.

Comment: doesn't probably help much, but note that base64 is an encoding, not an encryption

Comment: I don't know how to attach header to post request for auth. Therefore, I require your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#axios-api) you can send custom headers.

```
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  }, {
    auth: { // Only basic auth
    username: 'janedoe',
    password: 's00pers3cret'
  },
     headers: {
         'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
         'Authorization': 'Bearer 1223..'
     },

  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: There are two usernames and password, one in the header and second are the ones entered by the user. How to write it in code? Additionally, there is content-type and authorization.

Comment: Also, as per the doc, the request has been deprecated.

Comment: Updated the answer to use Axios library

Comment: Where to add the URL to make a request to LDAP API?